# Perl regex string or string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a query that could be worded as follows:

```
"Who is King?"
"Who was King?"
```

and then have an optional "a" or "the".

```
"Who is the King?"
"Who is a King?"
"Who was the King?"
"Who was a King?"
```

I'm trying to capture anything after "is" or "was" with the optional "a" or "the", in this instance it would be 'King'.

```
if($input =~ /[is|was]\s[the|a]?(.*)\?/g)
{
    $searchTerm = $1;
}
```

It all works except when I add "the" I get `he King`.

It seems what is happening is my `?` is catching 't' then moving on since I have it for 0 or one. But I was under the assumption `[the|a]?` would match 0 or 1 instance of 'the' or 'a'.

Can someone help with this regular expression?

Comment: Aren’t square brackets used for character classes?

Comment: You want to use parens, `if($input =~ /(?:is|was)\s(?:the|a)?(.+?)\?/)`

Comment: Can you explain the `?:` part please?

Comment: `(?:)` is non-capturing group (matched part doesn't go into $1, $2,..)

Comment: Visit [Regex101](https://regex101.com/#pcre) for all the RegEx stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specify a match of two or more choices, you separate the choices with the alternation symbol.

```
the|a
```

To specify the boundary or scope of the alternation, you must surround the alternate choices with parentheses.

```
(the|a)
```

Anything within parentheses also has the consequence that it becomes a capture group. To specify a non-capturing group you add `?:` after the opening parenthesis.

```
(?:the|a)
```

You very likely want to also allow the word "an" in addition to "the" and "a".

```
(?:the|a|an)
```

Since the word is optional (it can appear once or not at all), you need to place a `?` after the group.

```
(?:the|a|an)?
```

Furthermore, since the word is optional, the space before it should also be optional (but there should be at least one space if the word is present).

```
(\s+(?:the|a|an))?
```

Finally, the new group we just created to account for the leading space should also be specified as non-capturing.

```
(?:\s+(?:the|a|an))?
```

Here is a script which successfully parses your examples (as well as my own examples using the optional word "an"):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $input = <DATA>) {
  chomp $input;
  if ( my($subject) = $input =~ /\s+(?:is|was)(?:\s+(?:the|a|an))?\s+(.+)\?/ ) {
    print "$input: [$subject]\n";
  }
}

__DATA__
Who was King?
Who is King?
Who is the King?
Who is a King?
Who was the King?
Who was a King?
Who is Ace?
Who is the Ace?
Who is an Ace?
Who was Ace?
Who was the Ace?
Who was an Ace?
```

This outputs:

```
Who was King?: [King]
Who is King?: [King]
Who is the King?: [King]
Who is a King?: [King]
Who was the King?: [King]
Who was a King?: [King]
Who is Ace?: [Ace]
Who is the Ace?: [Ace]
Who is an Ace?: [Ace]
Who was Ace?: [Ace]
Who was the Ace?: [Ace]
Who was an Ace?: [Ace]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your alternation is wrong.  You want `(is|was)`, not `[is|was]`.

You also don't need the `/g` because you are not in a loop.

Your regex should look like:

```
if ( $input =~ /"(.+)\s+(is|was)\s+(the|a)\s+(.+)\?"/ ) {
    my $pronoun = $1;
    my $is_was  = $2;
    my $the_a   = $3;
    my $what    = $4;
}
```